# MVC orderby on dropdownlist

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I have a dropdown list that is set in a table.  I originally let the unique ID of the table be the control for the order of the list of items. However work have requested a change of this order. I could rearrange the table to it still orders using the unique Identifier but I believe this order will change regularly until they are happy. so I have added a field called zoneOrder.  The trouble I am having is how to order by using the below code

```
ViewBag.zoneId = new SelectList(db.tblZoneLists, "zoneId", "zoneDesc");
```

I have tried

```
ViewBag.zoneId = new SelectList(db.tblZoneLists, "zoneId", "zoneDesc").OrderByDescending(e=>e.zoneOrder)
```

but this doesn't work, in fact when I type the e=>e. the intellisense only gives me options such a 'value', 'text'

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to reorder that a bit:

```
ViewBag.zoneId = new SelectList(db.tblZoneLists
                                  .OrderByDescending(e=>e.zoneOrder), 
                 "zoneId", "zoneDesc")
```

The `SelectList` object is a list of `SelectListItem`s. Each `SelectListItem` has 3 properties: `Text`, `Value` and `Selected`. When you call `OrderByDescending` on the `SelectList`, you are actually trying to order a list of `SelectListItem`s. That's why Intellisense is suggesting the `Value` property.

Since you are trying to order your DropDownList, you should first order the data source, i.e. `tblZoneLists`. That's why you fist order the data and then pass it to the `SelectList` constructor.

Comment: Thankyou so much for this, it has been driving me mad for the last two hours, still trying to get my head around linq.

Comment: You did nothing "wrong" with Linq. You just used the wrong source object. See the documentation for [`SelectList`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.selectlist(v=vs.118).aspx) and  [`SelectListItem`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.selectlistitem(v=vs.118).aspx) for additional details.